# Why does it appear that a binding expression doesn't re-evaluate when properties it uses change?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to get a better understanding of AngularJs and it's digest cycles and I'm a bit confused as to why the code below doesn't work.

**JsFiddle** 
http://jsfiddle.net/RyanVice/3u2dp/

**Code**

```
<div ng-app>
    <input type="text" ng-model="input1"/>
    <input type="text" ng-mode="input2"/>
    {{ input1 === input2 }}
</div>
```

This code will change from displaying true to false after you enter the first character but then stops responding to changes in either input box. Why doesn't this keep re-evaluating?

**EDIT**

Wow, how embarrassing but thanks for helping me spot that typo. I had a follow up question that is related.

If I now wanted to show or hide a font awesome icon it seems like I could use a ng-show with the same binding expression. However the JsFiddle below only evaluates the binding expression on first load. It seems like it evaluates it at compile time (which can verify by changing the === to a !===) but never again. I know if I introduce a controller I can make this work but I'm trying to get a better understanding of the basics of binding expressions and digest cycles. Any idea why this doesn't work?

**JsFiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/RyanVice/3u2dp/1/

**Code**

```
<div ng-app>
    <input type="text" ng-model="input1"/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="input2"/>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" ng-show="{{ input1 === input2 }}"></span> 
    {{ input1 === input2 }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you have a typo. The below code works:

```
<div ng-app>
    <input type="text" ng-model="input1"/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="input2"/>
    {{ input1 === input2 }}
</div>
```

Change `ng-mode="input2"` to `ng-model="input2"` in your original code.

Comment: Thanks. Can you help me with my follow up question?

Comment: What is your follow up question?

Comment: I added it above. Wasn't expecting you to respond so quick, sorry.

Comment: No need for `{{ }}` in `ng-show`: `ng-show="{{ input1 === input2 }}"` should be `ng-show="input1 === input2"`.

Comment: Oh, I see. So the binding expression syntax is only needed when binding outside of a directive. And when setting directive properties, you can use AngularJS expressions in the same way that you can in a binding expression. Thanks so much Davin!

Answer (score 0):

Change `ng-mode` to `ng-model` on your second input :)

I just tried this in the fiddle and it works fine!